# Is the Hobbit's gold statue scene physically accurate or even possible?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, smaug

In the second Hobbit movie,

> when dwarves tried to kill Smaug with liquid gold, they managed to get him close to the mold of a fifty-foot high gold statue of a dwarven king.

Considering that liquid gold was poured into just one or two minutes earlier, completely filling the mold, which was then removed, could the statue be hard enough to hold its own weight for a few seconds without the mold and then completely liquefy itself again?

Is that scene physically accurate or even possible?

Comment: Feel free to correct errors or grammatically improve this question, as I am not a native english speaker. ;D

Comment: Keep in mind giant flying fire-breathing dragons are not physically accurate or possible :P

Comment: How big, and what was the mold made of? Gold has a fairly low specific heat and high thermal conductivity, so it's possible at least the outside had solidified enough to keep its shape while falling. It probably would have popped when it hit, though.

Comment: I think question is more appropriate for Physics.SE, as it deals with the behavior of liquid gold rather than any in-universe knowledge.

Comment: Edited to include the estimated height of the statue.

Comment: Those of us voting to close think this is a great question, but that it will get better answers on Physics.SE.

Comment: @AndresF. Fire-breathing might be possible. The creature would merely need to vomit or spit a flammable substance, and have an ignition mechanism in its mouth... biological organisms could easily concentrate the minerals necessary for this in things like teeth. And we already know "gigantic" is possible. (Flight too, but it's mutually incompatible with large size.)

Comment: @JohnO Smaug's belly glowed whenever he prepared to breath fire, so he doesn't work by that mechanism (at least in the films)

Comment: Could this question be _moved_ to Physics.SE or should I just repost it there? CC @DampeS8N